# RxAndroidBle : Periodic advertising scan

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, rxandroidble

I need to scan `ble` advertising permanently while i am not connected to my device to find it and know when connect to it (specific product). This scan is realized in foreground service to match 8.0 prerequisite.

To preserve a few battery, i want scan periodically (while respect the Android 7 limit of start amount/time). I see 2 differents implementations :

- Start the scan each X seconds and be able to stop it after Y seconds, the wait time will be X-Y.
  ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Scan‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Wait‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌Scan‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Wait
  |--------------|------|--------------|------|---
  |---------X-------->|---------X-------->|--- 
  |------Y----->‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ |-----Y----->‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ |---

- Start the scan for X seconds, wait for Y seconds, start the scan for X seconds etc..
  ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Scan‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Wait‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌Scan‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ ‌‌ Wait
  |--------------|------|--------------|------|---
  |------X---->|--Y->|------X---->|--Y->|---

I want to do it with Rx style and not with the simple timer (i am not an RX expert). I don't know what solution is better/easier to be developed.
This must be transparent to the client and must keep the original `RxAndroidBle` working, subscribe = start the process and unsubscribe = stop the process.

I suppose I have to use `Obersable.interval` but i don't see how to manage this
Any snippet/ example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Android BLE API has `BluetoothLeScanner` class which allows to start a scan using one of four modes:

- `SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY`—the scan is continuous
- `SCAN_MODE_BALANCED`—the scan is working for 2 seconds every 5 seconds
- `SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER`—the scan is working for 0.5 second every 5 seconds
- `SCAN_MODE_OPPORTUNISTIC`—the scan is working only when a different application starts it

The time measurements were performed by Nordic Semiconductors employee and released in a form of a [comprehensive guide](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/1046/what-to-keep-in-mind-when-developing-your-ble-andr/) for Android BLE developers.

The `RxAndroidBle` library also has a function `RxBleClient.scanBleDevices(ScanSettings, ScanFilter...)` which accepts the same modes inside a `ScanSettings` object.

If one would need to achieve different parameters of scanning it is possible to simply use a combintaion of `Observable.takeUntil()` and `Observable.repeatWhen()`:

```
Observable<ScanResult> lowLatencyScanObservable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
  new ScanSettings.Builder()
    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // make sure that the scanning will be always on by default
    .build()
);

Observable<ScanResult> periodicalScan = lowLatencyScanObservable
  .takeUntil(Observable.timer(SCAN_TIME, SCAN_TIMEUNIT)) // scan for a specific amount of time and then unsubscribe to the upstream
  .repeatWhen(completionObservable -> completionObservable.delay(PAUSE_TIME, PAUSE_TIMEUNIT)); // when the upstream will complete because of `takeUntil()` wait for the pause time and resubscribe to the upstream
```

One would still need to remember about the undocumented "feature" of API 24+ which prevents starting more than 5 scans during a 30 seconds period.

Comment: how do you know what each scan mode does? It's not documented, at least not in the ScanSettings class

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a link to a related Nordic Semiconductors forum post.

Comment: Thanks. Informative. It's a pity that this information is by a 3rd party, though, even if it's nordic

Comment: Thanks you, perfect solution :)